# How to implement custom listview with "stacking" feature Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-custom-view, horizontal-scrolling

I want to create a custom listview that scroll horizontally and stacks the last 4 items in the view instead of allowing them to go off screen. The stack should look something like this: [image]. So if a user scrolls all the way to the left they see a regular listview, but as they scroll right, if an item was supposed to go off screen, it is instead stacked behind the last item in the list, with a max of 4 stacks. What's a good basic way to accomplish this? I already found the [horizontally scrolling listview](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/it/sephiroth/android/library/widget/HListView.java) library I wanted to use but don't know where to start on the stacking part.

Comment: Take a look at Swipeable-Cards(https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards) lib. I think that's what you need:

Comment: I took a look at it but it doesnt handle what I needed. Instead I'm just going to implement my own view that inherits scrollview and contains a linearlayout in it where I will inflate each view. Then I'll listen for scroll changes in onScrollChanged() and adjust the child views as needed.